# Using regex in javascript to select only text between tags

Tags: javascript, regex, text

I've searched and searched but can't seem to find the answer I need. I'm still wrapping my head around the whole regex thing don't know enough to solve this problem, which seems far to simple.

I have a  string `"<a href="#">London<span>35.2miles</span></a>"`

I need to chop everything apart from `"London"`, but everything I try results in `"London<span>35.2miles</span>"` I cannot seem to get rid of the *span* tags and text, as well as the *a* tags.

Comment: Why regex? Isn't your `a` tag a dom element?

Comment: Cthulhu, my lord, he comes whilst virgin ponies wheep the blood of the unborn... or something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var root = document.createElement("div");
root.innerHTML = '<a href="#">London<span>35.2miles</span></a>';
alert( root.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue );
```

Comment: +1 for handling it as DOM element :) Jus added a comment for the same in OP

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression should work;

```
/>([^<]*)/
```

It matches anything from the first `>` until it hits another `<`

You can combine this with the `match()` method, to end up with something like this;

```
var matches = '<a href="#">London<span>35.2miles</span></a>'.match(/>([^<]*)/);

if (matches) { // "null" if no matches, array if there was.
    var london = matches[1];
}
```